# How to find Tailwind CSS className typo

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there a way to find typos/mistakes in Tailwind CSS classNames ?

For example, className typos can occur in spelling and other characters like dash/underscore:

```
 <FormLabel className="account_form-image-lable">
   ...
 </FormLabel>
```

But the correct code should be:

```
 <FormLabel className="account-form_image-label">
   ...
 </FormLabel>
```

But I got no warning or error when NextJs runs...

How can I find such error?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with an extension for VS Code - Tailwind CSS IntelliSense, but for some reason it doesn't work out for me (in terms of highlights errors in classes, everything else works fine).
Currently I run eslint plugin to find typos in classes (among other things)..